# Subfolder for testing

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

Can you help me with `.htaccess`? I have simple code

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

# front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

This code is ok if I use this one on root folder(localhost), but I need test this code on server in subfolder, where is the index.php too.

I use URL as `http://domain.com/parameter/parameter`, but i need now use `http://domain.com/folder_test/parameter/parameter`

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What's the problem, there is an error, no redirection? Please explain with examples of the `parameter`. And where is the .htaccess file, in root or in the `folder_test` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `#RewriteBase /` and make it `RewriteBase /your_folder/` and try

Comment: Try it, still same problem. If i try URL http://domain.com/folder_test/parameter/ Im redirect to http://domain.com/parameter/